# Shell variables in Google Colab Console

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab and I want to save this two files to my Drive with today's date, this doesn't seem to work. How can I workaround this?

Input

```
!read -p "Please enter today's date: " d
!cp f1_${d}.csv "drive/My Drive"
!cp f2_${d}.csv "drive/My Drive"
```

Output

```
Please enter today's date: 08-01-21
cp: cannot stat 'f1_/bin/bash8-01-21.csv': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'f2_/bin/bash8-01-21.csv': No such file or directory
```

I want the output files to be `f1_08-01-21.csv` and `f2_08-01-21.csv`.

Comment: The error message obviosuly relates to the **input**, not the *output*, so I don't understand the point of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that each `!command` runs in a separate subshell. The `read -p` runs, then exits, and the variable it read is no longer available, similarly to what would happen if you closed and reopened a notebook and tried to evaluate code blocks which depend on earlier code blocks you have not evaluated after restarting.

You don't need to input today's date manually anyway; your computer already knows.

```sh
!cp "f1_$(date +%F).csv" "drive/My Drive"
!cp "f2_$(date +%F).csv" "drive/My Drive"
```

If your desired date format isn't `%F` (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD), adapt to taste. (But keep in mind that it makes sense to have dates in computer-readable format; " 2 Aug 2021" is pleasant to read, but pesky to process. The one you are trying to use would be `date +%d-%m-%Y`, which is easy to recover, but hard e.g. to sort correctly.)

Comment: Also, as long as the destination is a directory, you can copy multiple files at once; `!cp "f1_$(date +%F).csv" "f2_$(date +%F).csv" "drive/My Drive"` or even `!cp f[12]_"$(date +%F).csv" "drive/My Drive"`